# Trying to insert into access database via SQL getting ID from another table

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

I have 2 tables in an Access database:

- **tblMachine**
- fields:
- MachineID
- MachineDescription
- **tblProblem**
- fields
- ProblemID
- MachineID
- ProblemDescription

I am trying to add a new record into tblProblem, using the MachineDescription to find the MachineID from tblMachine

However, my SQL statement throws an error on the sub-select statement

Here is my statement:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tblProblem" +
                " ([MachineID], [ProblemDescription], [ProblemOrder])" +
                " VALUES (" + 
                "(SELECT ([MachineID] FROM tblMachine WHERE MachineDescription = @MachineDescription))," +
                " @ProblemDescription, @ProblemOrder);";
```

The problem being highlighted is this part:

```
"(SELECT ([MachineID] FROM tblMachine WHERE MachineDescription = @MachineDescription)),"
```

Have I done something wrong? It is telling me there is a syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra set of parentheses, and perhaps unqualified field names:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblProblem " + 
    "([MachineID], [ProblemDescription], [ProblemOrder])" +
    "SELECT tblMachine.[MachineID], @ProblemDescription, @ProblemOrder " +
    "FROM tblMachine " +
    "WHERE tblMachine.MachineDescription = @MachineDescription";
```

Comment: still getting: Syntax error in query expression 'SELECT (tblMachine.[MachineID] FROM tblMachine WHERE tblMachine.[MachineDescription] = @MachineDescription)'.

Comment: Ok, I don't get an error any more, it seems to go through fine, but when I check the database there is no new record added

Comment: figured what the problem must have been - i was using oleDB, now i have a mySQL server, and that statement works perfectly... so belated thanks :)