# Getting rows from 2 tables

Tags: c#, mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

```
tblDowntime
downtimeID - downtimeDescription
1          - dt_desc
2          - dt_desc2


tblMachineArea
areaID     - downtimeID - areaDescription
1          - 1          - area1
2          - 2          - area2
```

I know the **downtimeDescription**, so what do I have to do to get the corresponding areas from tblMachineArea?

I can get them from the ID, but my listbox will only have the description

I have got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196689/trying-to-insert-into-access-database-via-sql-getting-id-from-another-table/17196771#17196771) for INSERT, but couldn't adapt it...unless I'm missing something really obvious...

My other question is what join to use... I have tried inner join with machineID = 1, it returns all the rows in tblMachineArea but with different machineID's depending on if I use 1 or 2 in the query.... doesn't make much sense to me

EDIT: the query I have run is

```
SELECT areaID, tblMachineArea.downtimeID, tblDowntime.downtimeDescription, areaDescription
FROM tblDowntime
INNER JOIN tblMachineArea ON tblMachineArea.downtimeID = 1;
```

image: (please forgive the table names and fields are slightly different, so I have updated the originals)
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show us the query you tried.

Comment: Since your data is only linked by ID you do not have a chance to get the corresponding records by using just the list boxes. You have to take the description from the list box holding the machines, search in your tblMachine for the related ID, and then search in tblDowntime for the correspoding records to that ID.

Comment: Inner Join should be the right way to retrieve the desired records. Please show your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid using joins and run two queries.

First get the ID of the machine and store that as a variable.  THen use that variable to get the info you need.

Also, the link you mentioned doesn't use prep`red statements, it's best to use that as a strategy if you can to improve security.

This is my PHP function for registering a user, you can see how the prepared statement is structured.

```
//function for registering a new user and adding their details to the database
public function register($username, $password, $email){

$time       = time();
$ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$emailCode = sha1($username + microtime());
$password   = sha1($password);

//prepare statement and bind values
$query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `ip`, `time`, `emailCode`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

$query->bindValue(1, $username);
$query->bindValue(2, $password);
$query->bindValue(3, $email);
$query->bindValue(4, $ip);
$query->bindValue(5, $time);
$query->bindValue(6, $emailCode);

try{
    $query->execute();

    //function stuff here removed to save space

}catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}   
 }//end register function
```

Comment: Frustratingly, this is what I ended up having to do, sorry for the late answer accept

Comment: No problem. Glad you got I worling